# Thread Console Application without Blocking using AutoResetEvent, ManualResetEvent, or Thread.Sleep

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am creating a Console Application that will do a lot of database processing.

I am doing the database collecting using a [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) control and writing to the Console through the [ProgressChanged event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged.aspx).

The problem is I need a way to keep the Console window open while the thread is running so that messages can post to it.

I am thinking something along these lines:

```
using (var worker = new BackgroundWorker())
{
    var mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    worker.DoWork += delegate(object s, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    // [SNIP] This code isn't related to the question
    worker.ProgressChanged += delegate(object s, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.UserState.ToString());
    };
    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += delegate(object s, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        mre.Set();
        // [SNIP] This code isn't related to the question
    }
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    Console.WriteLine("Import Started {0:G}", startTime);
    while (worker.IsBusy)
    {
        if (!mre.WaitOne(200))
        {
            mre.Reset();
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** It does not have to be in a `using` block; that just makes the code easy to show on here.

The problem is that I know that the [AutoResetEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx), the [ManualResetEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx), and the [Thread.Sleep](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.sleep.aspx) tools are all blocking routines - meaning my database calls will not be processed during this time.

I do not want that.

How could I write something to let the database processing continue while keeping the Console window open?

Comment: You are using a hammer in search of a nail.  There just isn't any point in using BGW when your main thread does not have anything useful to do.  You might as well keep it busy with the dbase query.  BGW is primarily useful to prevent a GUI app from freezing, not a console mode app problem.

Comment: @HansPassant: But hammers are tough, manly tools.

Comment: @HansPassant - actually, though, I am tying into an existing library that is thousands of lines long, currently is written for a BackgroundWorker, and posts information through the BackgroundWorker's ProgressChanged event. That seemed irrelevant to the question, though, so I didn't post it. Thanks for the downvote.

Comment: That wasn't my vote.  I can see how it happened though, *manly tools*??  Keep it professional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The problem is that I know that the AutoResetEvent, the
>   ManualResetEvent, and the Thread.Sleep tools are all blocking routines
>   - meaning my database calls will not be processed during this time.

No, they happen on a different thread in the DoWork callback:

```
worker.DoWork += delegate(object s, DoWorkEventArgs e)
```

So the `mre.WaitOne(200)` that you placed in the main thread to prevent your console application from existing will not block the database operations.

Comment: No kidding? That's great! I was thinking I was going to need to create a Timer and a callback. My existing way is much easier. Thanks Darin!

Comment: Actually the whole point of the `BackgroundWorker` class is that it execute the code specified in the `DoWork` callback on a different thread than the one it was created on.